# Is any closed-form representation known for the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)\log n}{n^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, closed-form

Is any closed-form representation known for the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)\log n}{n^2}$, where $\mu(n)$ is the [Möbius $\mu$-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use a series for the reciprocal [Riemann $\zeta$-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html): $\zeta(s)^{-1}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(n)n^{-s}$, then take a derivative with respect to $s$ and let $s=2$. This gives you $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)\log n}{n^2}=\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)^2}$. It is well-known that $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, and a closed form of the derivative is given in OEIS [A073002](http://oeis.org/A073002):

$\zeta'(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\left(\gamma+\log(2\pi)-12 \log A\right)$,

where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html), and $A$ is the [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html). Taking it all together, the result is:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)\log n}{n^2}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\left(\gamma+\log(2\pi)-12 \log A\right)$.

Comment: Very nice answer! Mathematica was not able to calculate this.

Comment: @ZakhariaStanley That says something about humans, no?